# insertMany с пропуском записей с дублирующимися ключами

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

В nodejs с использованием mongoose создается коллекция с указанием на то, что поле t должно быть уникальным:

```
const RSchema = new db.Schema({
    t: {type: Number, unique: true}
});
```

В коллекцию пишется массив:

```
коллекция.insertMany([{t: 1}, {t: 2}, {t: 3}])
```

все хорошо. Затем в коллекцию пишется второй массив:

```
коллекция.insertMany([{t: 3}, {t: 4}, {t: 5}])
```

при записи первого элемента массива возникает ошибка и процесс записи прерывается. Вопрос в том, как сделать так, чтобы во второй раз первый элемент просто игнорировался, а последующие успешно писались.

Answer (score 0):

Для этого требуется указать параметр ordered, установленный в значение false (по умолчанию этот параметр устанавливается в значение true)

```
коллекция.insertMany([{t: 3}, {t: 4}, {t: 5}], {ordered: false})
```

при этом дублирующие записи игнорируются, не дублирующие записи нормально вставляются и генерируется исключение E11000 duplicate key error index

этот параметр описан в документации [mongodb insert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/insert/)

> **ordered**   **boolean**  **Optional**. If true, then when an insert of a document fails, return without inserting any remaining documents listed in the inserts array. If false, then when an insert of a document fails, continue to insert the remaining documents. Defaults to true.